# How does Git parse date string?

Tags: git, date, time, jodatime

I have a date string from Joda DateTime.toString that reads like below:

`2020-04-03T12:43:55.019-04:00"`

If I do

`git commit --date="2020-04-03T12:43:55.019-04:00”`

and then `git log` to check out the date, it's returning `Sun Apr 19 12:43:55 2020 -0400` which seems wrong on the date part.

But if I change the time zone slightly from 04:00 to 05:00, Git seems to be parsing the date fine:

`git commit --date="2020-04-03T12:43:55.019-05:00”`

would give me the correct date time when I run `git log` command: `Fri Apr 3 12:43:55 2020 -0500`

What is wrong with the first date? Why does Git think it's from Apr 19 but not Apr 3?

Answer (score 2):

I think you found a bug.

`git-commit` claims it understands these formats, but it tries to understand a lot more.

```
   The GIT_AUTHOR_DATE, GIT_COMMITTER_DATE environment variables and the --date option
   support the following date formats:

   Git internal format
       It is <unix timestamp> <time zone offset>, where <unix timestamp> is the number
       of seconds since the UNIX epoch.  <time zone offset> is a positive or negative
       offset from UTC. For example CET (which is 1 hour ahead of UTC) is +0100.

   RFC 2822
       The standard email format as described by RFC 2822, for example Thu, 07 Apr
       2005 22:13:13 +0200.

   ISO 8601
       Time and date specified by the ISO 8601 standard, for example
       2005-04-07T22:13:13. The parser accepts a space instead of the T character as
       well.

           Note
           In addition, the date part is accepted in the following formats:
           YYYY.MM.DD, MM/DD/YYYY and DD.MM.YYYY.
```

`2020-04-03T12:43:55.019-04:00` is a perfectly valid [ISO 8601 datetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) in the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss±hh:mm. It should work. For example, here's Ruby on Rails.

```
[1] pry(main)> Time.parse("2020-04-03T12:43:55.21-04:00")
=> 2020-04-03 12:43:55 -0400
```

Git appears to be confused the fractional seconds and uses them as the month day. And yes, there also seems to be something about the -04:00 time zone in particular.

- `git commit --date='2020-04-03T12:43:55.021-04:00'` -> Tue Apr 21 12:43:55 2020 -0700 (with fractional seconds, 0400 offset, incorrect)
- `git commit --date='2020-04-03T12:43:55-04:00'` -> Fri Apr 3 12:43:55 2020 -0400 (no fractional seconds, 0400 offset, correct)
- `git commit --date='2020-04-03T12:43:55.021-05:00'` -> Fri Apr 3 12:43:55 2020 -0500 (fractional seconds, 0500 offset, correct)
- `git commit --date='2020-04-03T12:43:22.023-04:00'` -> Thu Apr 23 12:43:22 2020 -0700 (factional seconds, incorrect)
- `git commit --date='2020-04-03T12:43:22.024-04:00'` -> Fri Apr 3 12:43:22 2020 -0400 (correct)

My guess is something in Git's ad hoc parsing is reading "21-04" as the date April 21st. For example.

- `git commit --date='12:43:22 23-04'` -> Thu Apr 23 12:43:22 2020 -0700

<strike>Why it cuts off at April 23rd I have no idea.</strike>

It likely cuts off at 23 because there is no hour 24.

The bug is likely in [match_multi_number in date.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/date.c#L542).

Comment: Git doesn't store or handle fractional seconds in any way, so you should not pass it fractional seconds.  It does handle a variety of formats using its (undocumented) approxidate code, and you're hitting the case of it parsing the dot as a date separator.

Comment: @bk2204 Git claims to accept ISO 8601, it should accept and ignore fractional seconds; this makes it a lot easier to pass ISO timestamps into Git without first having to strip out the parts Git does not use. While the dot is involved in confusing it, it does not appear to be reading it as a date separator; `22.023` does not make sense as a date.

Comment: You're welcome to send a bug report or a patch to the list.  I'm just telling you what it does right now and what you should do if you want things to work as it stands.

Comment: @bk2204 I'd take a crack at it, but doing my taxes is simpler than [the Git bug report and patching process](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/SubmittingPatches).

Answer (score 0):

> Git appears to be confused the fractional seconds and uses them as the month day

The bug mentioned and addressed by [Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61197722/6309) starts to be fixed with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), where the `approxidate` parser **learns to parse seconds with fraction**.

See [commit 544ed96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/544ed961a50c3442a3ec5643f2c443cd3e17311a), [commit b784840](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b784840ca84c708708d1ab0b872eb3a6fb3200b5), [commit 4f89f4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f89f4fc9ac494fde3f3bede19a7599f77afe8dc) (24 Apr 2020), and [commit c933b28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c933b28d87062a0c68de298900b9060f577f865a) (23 Apr 2020) by [Đoàn Trần Công Danh (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cdfa156](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdfa156a93ffb2e0bb2a25714e2c2e74dfa71fd9), 05 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`date.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b784840ca84c708708d1ab0b872eb3a6fb3200b5): skip fractional second part of ISO-8601
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Brian M. Carlson</sup>
>   <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Đoàn Trần Công Danh</sup>
>
> git-commit(1) says ISO-8601 is one of our supported date format.
>
> ISO-8601 allows timestamps to have a fractional number of seconds. We represent time only in terms of whole seconds, so we never bothered parsing fractional seconds.
>   However, it's better for us to parse and throw away the fractional part than to refuse to parse the timestamp at all.
>
> And refusing parsing fractional second part may confuse the parse to think fractional and timezone as day and month in this example:
>
> ```
> 2008-02-14 20:30:45.019-04:00
> ```
>
> While doing this, make sure that we only interpret the number after the second and the dot as fractional when and only when the date is known, since only ISO-8601 allows the fractional part, and we've taught our users to interpret "`12:34:56.7.days.ago`" as a way to specify a time relative to current time.

Answer (score -1):

Its parsing is ad-hoc and it could certainly handle this input better (or just reject it), but your times are ill-formed.  TZ offsets don't have colons.

```
git commit --date=2020-04-03T12:43:55.019-0400    # <-- `-0400`, not `-04:00`.
```

works.

edit: I see the ISO rules for timestamps allow the `:` in the offset where the RFC 822 rules don't, that's probably the source of confusion here.

Somehow I just can't get worked up enough about this to cook up a patch, though.

Comment: Thx for the reply. The thing I don't understand is that Git seems to be able to parse the date time string with -05:00 in TZ offsets but not -04:00 (which BTW is the standard output by calling Joda DateTime.toString). Seems very random to me.

Comment: Yah, Git's running on the older RFC822 rules for time zones, it's arguably a bug in the modern world but I'd expect it'd take a patch, not just a report, to get it fixed.